# Single table SELF JOIN alternatives / except / intersect

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on a query, which searches books from a table based on its attributes. The table contains more than 50 million row has the following structure:

```
-----------------------
| book_id | attr_id   |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 35021     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 28106     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 27173     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 35109     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 34999     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 35107     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 35099     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 35105     |
-----------------------
| 2005207 | 28224     |
-----------------------
| ...     | .....     |    
-----------------------
```

The attribute column is representing attributes, such as binding, publishing year, genre and many more. The **primary key** is a compound  key attr_id, book_id

One example query could be "Find all books, where genre is either comic or science fiction without hardcover".

```
SELECT sql_no_cache a.book_id
FROM
  (SELECT book_id
   FROM attribute_books ab
   WHERE ab.attr_id IN (38571,
                        38576)) a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT book_id
   FROM attribute_books ab
   WHERE ab.attr_id = 35003) b ON b.book_id = a.book_id
AND b.book_id IS NULL;
```

These kind of queries can be self joined multiple times and currently have a very poor performance. Instead of an inner join for IN statements and left joins for NOT IN statements, I could also use the intersect command, which is available in some SQL flavors.

I currently have the following questions:

1. Is this the most efficient kind of queries for similar queries. If not, are there any suggestions for speeding this up?
2. Should I switch to an entirely different type of database / engine, such as  for more efficient (faster) queries?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the most efficient method is `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from books b
where not exists (select 1
                  from attribute_books ab
                  where ab.attr_id in (38571, 38576) and b.book_id = ab.book_id
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from attribute_books ab
              where ab.attr_id = 35003 and b.book_id = ab.book_id
             )
```

For this, you want an index on `attribute_books(book_id, attr_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT book_id
FROM attribute_books
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN attr_id IN (38571, 38576) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN attr_id = 35003 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The first `HAVING` clause checks that the genre is either comedy or science fiction, and the second `HAVING` clause checks that the book is not hardcover.  You may extend this query by adding or removing other key value pairs.

Comment: That actually sound like a good idea. However, the downside of the query is that HAVING is evaluated after the JOIN. After running some test against the database, the solution with HAVING is slower than the self join.

Comment: @bumblebee Perhaps, but your current approach would require adding a new join for each key.